# Can't get Pagemethods to work c# asp.net ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have been trying for a while.  I have a jquery datatable that I have set an onclick method on the table .  I know the click is working because I had an alert set to give me a piece of data from the row.  My next step is to take a piece of data 'Quote_Num' an integer from column 0.  And set it as a session variable (with pagemethods) and then call the Quote Form which looks for this variable and if present sets the form with the information from my database.  Long story short you click the row from the quote table you get a page with the quotes data.

When I click a row in the Quote table I am redirected to quote.aspx but the session variable is not set.  So the program gets to the OnSuccessCallBack method but never executes the code in the c# method.  I set a breakpoint in the c# method but never reached. The ajax response seems to be an entire web page. Also I have a script manager with pagemethods set to true in the master page.

aspx

```
 $('#Quote').dataTable({
          "info": false,
          "scrollY": "100px",
          "scrollCollapse": true,
          "paging": false,                                                              
          "lengthChange": false,
          "columnDefs": [{
              "targets": 0,
              "visible": false,
              "searchable": false
          }]                                                    
      });

      var qTable = $('#Quote').DataTable();

      $('#Quote tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
          var quote = qTable.row(this).data()[0];
          PageMethods.quoteAdd(quote, OnSuccessCallback, OnFailureCallback);
      });

  })

  function OnSuccessCallback() {
      document.location.href = "QuoteFrm.aspx";
  }

  function OnFailureCallback() {
      alert('Error');
  }
```

cs;

```
     [WebMethod]
    public static void quoteAdd(int Quote_Num)
    {
        Page objp = new Page();
        objp.Session.Add("Quote", Quote_Num);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `enableSession` in your web method. Something like this.

```
//cs head
using System.Web.Services;

[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
public static void addQuot(string name)
{
    //this is how to access Session object in a static method
    HttpContext.Current.Session["name"] = name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input Alex.  Made your suggested changes but still not working.  I put a breakpoint in the addQuote() method never was reached. Just opens quoteFrm.aspx without session variable.

Comment: Check your console. Are there any errors? Also check request and response.

Comment: No console errors and the response seems to be a web page I used chrome developer tools network section it showed addQuote I selected it and then checked the response

Comment: For test purpose change `void` to `string` and `return HttpContext.Current.Session["Quote"];`. Change `window.location...` to `console.log(data)`. Add parameter `data` to `function OnSuccessCallback(data){...}`. Check request (POST). It should be `{"Quote_Num":1}`. Make sure that `var quote = qTable.row(this).data()[0];` is `int`.

Comment: Ok I changed void to string and added return httpCon............... as string (didn't like object to string).  Changed document.location........ to console.log(data).  This gave me a bunch of html to the console.  Don't know how to check request(POST) and not sure how to verify var quote is int except that is what the column contains (an integer identity field from database)

Comment: Do you set `<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>` ?

Comment: Yes in the master page.  I can't believe it's not working everything I read says it should be.  Very frustrating

Comment: Reduce it to a single `.aspx` page without `.master` to locate the problem.